Finding the real origin of block I/O (submit_bio) using eBPF
I have an I/O tracer which uses eBPF, and traces read and write operations at the different levels of the I/O stack (VFS, File System, Page cache, and Block).
I want to trace a couple of benchmarks (FIO, Postmark, YCSB, TeraSort), and my tracer can filter events by command or multiple commands specified as arguments.
The problem i'm having is at the block level, where I want to trace events only originating from the benchmarks and not other applications, but some of these benchmarks cause the blocks I/Os to be done by other commands such as kworker or btrfs-transaction, I have noticed these because i've attempted tracing the entire system with no filtering and I can clearly see an elevated number of block events when I run a benchmark compared to an idle system.
Please note that not every benchmark behaves like this because i've been able to trace FIO without issues
I'm hoping to find a way to get the origin of block level I/Os that are done by kworker processes or others, in order to avoid tracing every block I/O. (or any other solution to my problem really)
I have tried various kprobes other than submit_bio but I still face the same issue using them
